# How do I show that the Möbius band and $S^1$ are homotopy equivalent?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, mobius-band

First of all I know that this post isn't really well since I don't have done much work but the problem is that I really have no idea how to deal with this problem, therefore I hope that nobody close it since for me it would be helpful.

I need to show that the Möbius band and $S^1$ are homotopy equivalent. I can do this either by presenting the explicit homotopy or appropriate picture.
But unfortunately I have no idea. I only know how the Möbius band looks like but I don't see how to do this in picture and therefore I'm also lost finding a homotopy.

Could someone help me please?

Thank you for your help

Comment: It would be better if you explain what tools you have available, how you are defining the Möbius band, if you know a parametrisation, etc. For example, once you have a parametrisation, showing it retracts onto its central circle is very easy. In particular, please avoid *I have no idea* posts (i.e. your first paragraph).

Comment: the problem is that we have never defined it, it only appears in an exercice without information

Comment: This is not something an "outsider" can fix for you. You need to talk with your instructor or classmates to find out what definition of the band you're all using, and if you're not using any, then maybe look at one you like and go with that one. Else, you are leaving all the work for someone else...

Comment: So but isn't there some intuition one can give for drawing such homotopies, because there are much more exercises and we only have pictures with no informations.

Comment: This question has been asked many times in this forum. See https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=m%C3%B6bius+band+circle .

Comment: sorry but this doesn't help me much since I don't see how to think about this graphically and thus I don't understand the way they prove it